# Cómo hago un smooth scroll a un componente de React (usando bootstrap)

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs, scroll, componentes

Estoy intentando hacer un s**mooth scroll desde los links del navbar** a mis componentes de react pero como use bootstrap hay un montón de cosas que no puedo hacer. Alguien puede ayudarme? Probé con react router pero capaz no lo use bien, estoy un poco confundida.Dejo el código para hacer el de form que es el único componente de la página que hice hasta ahora.

Componente MenuOptions:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import { Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const MenuOption = (props) => {
    const {to, label} = props
    return(
        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={to}>{label}</Nav.Link>
    );
};

export default MenuOption;
```

Componente Menu

```
import React from 'react';

import MenuOption from '../../Components/Menu/MenuOptions';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../../Components/Menu/Menu.css'

const Menu = () => {
    return(
    <div className="navbar-container sticky-top">
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="navbar-menu">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    ***<MenuOption className="hire-class" to="/form" label="CONTRATAR"/>***
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Menu
```

Gracias :)